# Write data in one line

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data written in a csv file in the format below:

```
[(789,255,25,33.0),(855,275,25,33.0)............]
```

I want it to be converted into a format like:

```
1. 789,255,25,33.0
2. 855,275,25,33.0
   ..............
```

So all i want is convert the tuples in the list into a new csv file with each tuple in a new line. The values in the list are in string and i want to convert it into float as well how do i accomplish it?

Comment: Can you post your logic over here?

Comment: Logic is already here - 
So all i want is convert the tuples in the list into a new csv file with each tuple in a new line. The values in the list are in string and i want to convert it into float as well how do i accomplish it?
What else?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `csv` module and `enumerate`.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
data = [(789,255,25,33.0),(855,275,25,33.0)]
with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for i, line in enumerate(data, 1):
        writer.writerow([i]+ list(line))
```

Using Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = [(789,255,25,33.0),(855,275,25,33.0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(filename, header=None)
```

Comment: Good, i get the output but i am getting a comma instead of a dot. 
`1,789,255,25,33.0

2,855,275,25,33.0`